# Confusion about chain conditions on operator groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $3.1.7.$ Each of the properties max-$\Omega$, max-$\Omega$s, min-$\Omega$, min-$\Omega$s is closed with respect to forming extensions. Thus, if $N\lhd G$ and $N$ and $G/N$ have the property in question, then so does $G$.

This is a theorem from Robinson's *A Course in the Theory of Groups* (GTM 80). Here max-$\Omega$/min-$\Omega$ means ascending/descending chain condition or maximal/minimal condition on $\Omega$-subgroups, and max-$\Omega$s/min-$\Omega$s means the corresponding properties on $\Omega$-subnormal subgroups. Then the auther says:

> In particular $3.1.7$ applies to the properties max, max-n, max-s, min, min-n, min-s.

Here max/min means max-$\Omega$/min-$\Omega$ when $\Omega=\varnothing$, max-n/min-n means max-$\Omega$/min-$\Omega$ when $\Omega=\operatorname{Inn}G$, and max-s/min-s means max-$\Omega$s/min-$\Omega$s when $\Omega=\varnothing$.

My confusion is this. What does it mean by $N$ and $G/N$ satisfy max-n/min-n? Should the operator domain be interpreted as $\operatorname{Inn}G$, or as $\operatorname{Inn}N$ or $\operatorname{Inn}G/N$?

If the answer is $\operatorname{Inn}G$, then the notation max-n/min-n seems ambiguous. What's more, the author then says the properties max-n and min-n are not inherited by subgroups, which I think is impossible if the operator domain has been unchanged all along. I think that all $\Omega$-subgroups of a $\Omega$-group with max-$\Omega$/min-$\Omega$ satisfy max-$\Omega$/min-$\Omega$. Is that correct? I think I can prove it, but due to the failure of understanding this point, I'm not sure.

If the answer is $\operatorname{Inn}N$ or $\operatorname{Inn}G/N$, then the operator domain has actually been changed. In this case I don't think the proof given in the book applies. Here is the proof:

> ***Proof*.** For example take the case of max-$\Omega$s. Let $N\lhd G$ where $G$ is an $\Omega$-group and $N$ an $\Omega$-subgroup. Suppose that $N$ and $G/N$ both have max-$\Omega$s, but that nevertheless there exists an infinite ascending chain $H_1<H_2<\cdots$ of $\Omega$-subnormal subgroups of $G$. Now $H_i\cap N$ is $\Omega$-subnormal in $N$ and $H_iN/N$ is $\Omega$-subnormal in $G/N$: hence there is an $r>0$ such that $H_r\cap N=H_{r+1}\cap N$ and $H_rN=H_{r+1}N$. But Exercise $1.3.16$ shows that $H_r=H_{r+1}$.

Of course, Exercise $1.3.16$ is the modular law for groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since max-n and min-n supposed to be a property of a single group, then I think the answer has to be that the operators of $N$ and of $G/N$ are ${\rm Inn}(N)$ and ${\rm Inn}(G/N)$.

There is no  problem with the proof, because when we try and prove that the property holds in $G$, the intersections of the subgroups in the chain with $N$ are being assumed invariant under ${\rm Inn}(G)$ (i,e. normal in $G$), and so they are also invariant under ${\rm Inn}(N)$ and we can apply the assumed property of $N$.

On the other hand the fact that $G$ satisfies max-n or min-n does not imply that $N$ does for $N \unlhd G$, so the converse of this resut is false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that the proof can be applied to max-n/min-n, but *with appropriate modifications*. But the proof assumes that the operator domain has been unchanged all along. So just another question: Are max-$\Omega$/min-$\Omega$ inherited by subgroups and quotients, with $\Omega$ unchanged? For example, if $N\lhd G$ and $G$ satisfies max-$\operatorname{Inn}G$, then $N$ and $G/N$ satisfy max-$\operatorname{Inn}G$?

Comment: Yes, provided that $N$ is $\Omega$-invariant, $N$ and $G/N$ will inherit max- and min-$\Omega$ from $G$.

Comment: Thank you so much! My confusion is completely clarified. :)